# Centering Scroll to Element to via # ? (without modifying the DOM / using refs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to scroll to a certain element via `#`:

`<a href="#element">Element</a>`

`<div name="element" />`

It accomplishes this quite well, but it goes to the very top of the element. However, I'd like the element scrolled to to be centered for the user.

I am hesitant to use Javascript's `scrollTo` or other, external libraries, since I will need to use this functionality a lot (very, very much). I am using React and don't want to overuse `refs` and slow down my app. So I'd like to accomplish this with HTML only, preferably. JS is fine too, of course, but **most solutions I came across modify the DOM and/or use `refs`.**

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better/cleaner way to do it, but with only html/css, the only thing that I think about is to use a hidden span under your div element, like so:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#element {
  position: relative;
  top: -50vh;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#element">Element</a>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <p> some text </p>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <p> some text </p>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Your element
    </p>
    <span id="element">anchor </span>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no way to achieve your desirable effect without a bit of js. As for "centered", then some calculation is needed.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .placeholder {
        height: 1000px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function scrollToDest(event) {
        var id = event.target.getAttribute("href");
        if (id.charAt(0) !== "#") return; // not a valid <a> element
        var dest = document.getElementById(id.substr(1));
        if (!dest) return; // no destination found;

        event.preventDefault();
        // calculate the top and bottom margin remained when dest is centered
        var margin = window.innerHeight - dest.clientHeight;
        // what if the dest's height is larger than viewport?
        if (margin < 0) margin = 0;
        window.scroll({ left: 0, top: dest.offsetTop - margin / 2, behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="placeholder">
      <a href="#dest" onclick="scrollToDest(event)">Let's go!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="dest">ARRIVAL</div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```